# How to disable the touch listener for some duration in Android

Tags: java, android, listener, touch-event, disable

I have a code which has set of buttons listening for touch events.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
    String btnid = "btn" + i;
    int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id", getPackageName());
    mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
    mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

But I am also using the TTS engine and I need to synchronize the speaking events with the touch events.

For that purpose I need to disable the touch listener for the buttons for some duration and then enable them after my work is done.

I want to write a method which can enable and disable touch events as per my requirements.

Comment: Only Two way btn.setEnabled(false); ,Second btn.setOnTouchListner(null);

Comment: @SamirMangroliya: I like your comment, you should reopen the question and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the Android touch listener you need to disable below properties...

```
 btn.setFocusable(false);

 btn.setClickable(false);
```

or

```
 btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: so i can reenable the functionality using btn.setEnabled(true); am i right??

Comment: Use `btn.setEnabled(false)` to temporarily disable it and then `btn.setEnabled(true)` to enable it again. Then use `btn.setOnTouchListner(null)` to remove it completely.